# regular expression on vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I have a log file like this:

```
some strings...
<FX>
another strings...
<FX>
 <TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
some strings...
<FX>
<FX>
 <TEG1>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
```

I need to parse it and get this results:

```
<FX>
 <TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
```

And

```
<FX>
 <TEG3>
 </TEG3>
</FX>
```

I have already wrote regular expression like this:

```
<FX>([\s\S]+?)</FX>
```

But it returns this matches:

```
<FX>
another strings...
<FX>
 <TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
```

And

```
<FX>
<FX>
 <TEG1>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
```

Can anybody help me with regular expression? 
Thanks in advane.

Comment: You may try using an XML parser instead of Regex for this. In VBScript you can use `msxml` for instance.

Comment: @MaxiWheat - the size (10 GB) and the fact that the data is malformed make using msxml impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what hides behind your "another strings", you may get away with:

```
  Dim sAll : sAll = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\15168620.txt").ReadAll()
  WScript.Echo sAll
  WScript.Echo "--------"
  Dim reX  : Set reX = New RegExp
  reX.Global  = True
  reX.Pattern = "<FX>[\s\S]*?(<FX>[\s\S]+?</FX>)"
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = reX.Execute(sAll)
  Dim oMT
  For Each oMT in oMTS
      WScript.Echo oMT.SubMatches(0)
      WScript.Echo "--------"
  Next
```

output:

```
some strings...
<FX>
another strings...
<FX>
 <TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
some strings...
<FX>
<FX>
 <TEG1>
 </TEG1>
</FX>

--------
<FX>
 <TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
--------
<FX>
 <TEG1>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
--------
```

**Update:**

I still hope that we can avoid a pedestrian approach:

```
  Dim sAll : sAll = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\15168620-2.txt").ReadAll()
  WScript.Echo sAll
  WScript.Echo "--------"
  Dim aAll : aAll = Split(sAll, "FX>")
  Dim sTry
  For Each sTry In aAll
      If "</" = Right(sTry, 2) Then
         WScript.Echo "<FX>" & sTry & "FX>"
         WScript.Echo "--------"
      End If
  Next
```

Output:

```
some strings...
<FX>
another <FX> strings...
<FX><FX><FX><FX><FX>
<FX>
<FX>
 <TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
some strings...
<FX>
<FX>
 <TEG1>
 </TEG1>
</FX>

--------
<FX>
 <TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
--------
<FX>
 <TEG1>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
--------
```

**Update II:**

The pedestrian approach - read line by line, start a new collection on **each** `<FX>`, process/output collection on `</FX>`:

```
  Dim alLines : Set alLines = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
  alLines.Capacity = 500
  Dim oTS     : Set oTS     = goFS.OpenTextFile("..\data\15168620-2.txt")
  Do Until oTS.AtEndOfStream
     Dim sLine : sLine = oTS.Readline()
     Select Case True
       Case "<FX>" = Left(sLine, 4)
            alLines.Clear
            alLines.Add sLine
       Case "</FX>" = Left(sLine, 5)
            alLines.Add sLine
            WScript.Echo Join(alLines.ToArray(), vbCrLf)
            WScript.Echo "--------"
       Case Else
            alLines.Add sLine
     End Select
  Loop
  oTS.Close
```

output:

```
<FX>
 <TEG1>
  <TEG2>
  </TEG2>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
--------
<FX>
 <TEG1>
 </TEG1>
</FX>
--------
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You asked a good question "Depending on what hides behind your "another strings"". Sometimes my "another strings" could contain many open tag <FX> sometimes it could contain simple text like "errors in db...". Maybe algorithm should be like this: in matches string find "last" tag <FX> and get all information between <FX> and </FX> tags. But how it write by regular expression - I don't know...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have tested it on my example and it workes fine for me, but how it would be worke on log file which has 10 Gb size (that's why I want to write regular expression)? I will test it on my work on Monday and tell you about rezults. Otherwise thank you)

Comment: @lurii - neither the RegExp nor the Split() approach are suited to process a file that can't be loaded into memory in full. We'll need a pedestrian strategy.

Answer (score 0):

With so huge file (10 GB), `RegExp` is worthless. Here is my idea.

```
' StripInvalidXML.vbs
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0
Const TAG_OPEN = "<FX>", TAG_CLOSE = "</FX>"

Dim fso, fin, fout
Dim sLine, sBlock

Set fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fin  = fso.OpenTextFile("input_log.xml",  ForReading,  False)
Set fout = fso.OpenTextFile("output_log.xml", ForAppending, True)

Do Until fin.AtEndOfStream
    sLine = fin.ReadLine
    If sLine = TAG_OPEN Then
        sBlock = sLine
    Else
        sBlock = sBlock & sLine
    End If
    sBlock = sBlock & vbNewLine
    If sLine = TAG_CLOSE Then
        fout.WriteLine sBlock
    End If
Loop

fin.Close
fout.Close
```